# Change the title of a Firefox tab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I would like to manually change the title of a tab in Firefox (I use one tab title which in turn uses the title when saving a tab).

Eventually I'm looking for the least time consuming method, but for now any method easier then the one I'm using (see below) will do.

Please note: It has to work on website where I can't change the code being set to the browser. The title change must occur after the fact. I haven't considered any problem that the manual title gets lost if the website in the tab gets reloaded - at least not yet. But if I do I will look to keep a tab from reloading.

**The solution I'm already using:**
Using the debug tool and change the title tag in the header of the website, this works well but is very time intensive:

- Shift + F5 to open tools
- Navigate to Inspektor tab (or use Crtl+Shif+C directly)
- Open header section
- Find the title tag (sometimes difficult to find)
- Edit the title tag and hit enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `document.title` property through JavaScript (e.g. using DevTools Console <kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>).

```
document.title = "Hello?"
```

You can create a bookmarklet with this URL: *(select and drag to the bookmark bar)*

```
javascript:void(document.title=prompt("New title?",document.title))
```

Comment: The bookmarklet would work perfectly if I want to write a new title. In order to "change" it, is it possible to use the current title as the default entry for the input dialogue?

Comment: Include the old title as a second parameter to prompt(), as in the updated post.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you can execute javascript through the bookmark...  I think I have to read up a little bit!

Comment: It used to be [a thing](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html) before WebExtensions became widespread.